# What is the best way to fill updated data from one aggregate root to another?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I try understand what is the best way for filling property from one Aggregare Root to another.

I have `Model Aggregate Root`, `Category Aggregate Root`, `Filter Aggregate Root`

Every `Model` can have some `Filter` list, and can be in one of the `Category`. `Category` can have a `Filter` for inheriting to the `Model`. When `Category` property of the `Model` is updated, `Filter` must be inherited from `Category` to the `Model`, and when `Filter` property is updated in the `Category`, all `Models` from that `Category` must inherit new value. All inherited `Filters` can't be updated, but manually added filters can be edited.

One way I "invent" is using `Process manager` with state which contains `Category filter` and `Models list`.

So I will have such behavior:

1. `Category AR` UpdateCategoryFilter (command) -> CategoryFilterUpdated (event)
2. `Model AR` AddCategory (command) -> CategoryAdded (event), RemoveCategory (command) -> CategoryRemoved (event), InheritFilter (command) -> FilterInherited (event), RemoveInheritedFilter (command) -> InheritedFilterRemoved (event)
3. `Filter AR` CreateFilter (command) -> FilterCreated (event)
4. Process Manager `FilterInheritance` have `correlationIdResolver` by `categoryId`, triggers on [`CategoryFilterUpdated`, `CategoryUpdated`] events

PM behavior is like:

```
current State(filter, models) =>
  if CategoryFilterUpdated(... newFilter ...) =>
    set new State(... newFilter ...) {
      models.forEach(send InheritFilter(model, newFilter))
    }
  if CategoryAdded(.... modelId ...) =>
    set new State(... models.add(modelId) ... ) {
      send InheritFilter(modelId, filter)
    }
  if CategoryRemoved(.... modelId ...) =>
    set new State(... models.remove(modelId) ... ) {
      send RemoveInheritedFilter(modelId, filter)
    }
```

Is this a right way? Is there some other ways?

Comment: Why do you call this code a "process manager"? What kind of process it manages, when does the process start and when does it end?

Comment: This is some pseudo code. It it `some ` which listens stream of events and changes his state (`State(filter, models)`) with sending commands (`InheritFilter(model, filter)`) when relevant events (`CategoryFilterUpdated`, `CategoryUpdated`) appears.

Comment: That was not my question. My question is what is your process? There is no process there, just several event handlers.

Answer (score 3):

Remember, Aggregates are for protecting domain invariants when making state changes, not for simple CRUD. It's not clear what your domain is, and what kind of commands might be sent to a 'Model' where protecting invariants requires knowing what the 'Filters' of the Model are.

You only need to send a command to an Aggregate if the command needs to be validated against the state of the aggregate, or if the command will affect handling of future commands that might be sent to the aggregate. It's not clear whether this is the case for you. Does the Model aggregate have to validate commands/emit events based on the Filters it has? If not, the way to handle this is to do it purely on the read-side - the read side can keep track of the current filter for a Model, and clients/processes can use it as necessary. So, your Model read projection will just need to listen for CategoryAdded, CategoryFilterUpdated, etc. to update the read view of the Model.

If you really do need the Filters to validate Model commands or emit appropriate events in response to those commands, then what you've got seems like an option. But examining your business requirements to see whether filtering could be done outside of the Model aggregate, etc. would be valuable, since copying commands between aggregates increases coupling - you also have a race condition between sending the InheritFilter, etc. commands and the client sending a command to the Model that needs that filter, which seems like a problem that might need client handling to poll for the Model to be ready for the command.

Comment: Thanks for "Aggregates are for protecting domain invariants when making state changes, not for simple CRUD". I think this is the main "core" and this is the hard part of the step from CRUD pattern.

Answer (score 2):

It looks very much like you are doing CRUD style data manipulation operations rather than taking a domain approach.

Another issue you may be having is assuming you can use Aggregate's to display information on the UI. Aggregates don't in principle have any externally visible properties (no getters except the ID). If they did they wouldn't be well encapsulated. You are better off using a read model for use on the UI. This article may give you a better overview of how a typical CQRS application is structured: [CQRS + Event Sourcing – A Step by Step Overview](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/10/02/cqrs-step-step-guide-flow-typical-application/?utm_source=social&utm_medium=stackoverflow)

Assuming you are looking to use a DDD style approach I would first have a look at your aggregates. I don't know your domain but from a surface view, it looks like just 1 aggregate root. Not sure what it would be called as I don't know anything about your domain.

I wouldn't expect, for example, real users would say things like "InheritFilter". You may also wish to take a look at this article to help you with how to name your events and by implication, your commands: [6 Code Smells with your CQRS Events – and How to Avoid Them](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/10/18/6-code-smells-cqrs-events-avoid/?utm_source=social&utm_medium=stackoverflow)

I hope this helps clear up some of your issues. I personally found getting my head around DDD, CQRS and event sourcing very difficult. I was having to unlearn a bunch of stuff. But I'm a better developer because of it.

Hope this helps.